# Using lollipops/sockets in UML, why and when?

Tags: uml

I have been going over some books and some articles to refresh my memory on class diagrams with UML.

I have stumbled upon something i have not known before and that's the lollipops and sockets relations (where lollipops are provided interfaces and sockets are required interfaces).

But I cant seem to wrap my head around when and why to use them.
From what I remember about interfaces and and class diagrams, the use of interfaces is done by A realization arrow (I create some interface and some other class will realize it).

So when will i want to use a lollipop association?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sockets show a uses dependency between some client classifier and the provider of the interface. This indicates that the client classifier uses any implementation of the interface.

Comment: What is the difference between doing a regular realization arrow.
I have any number of class's that Implements an interface. (all with a realization arrow to that interface).
that means exactly the same. who ever uses that interface can use all implementations provided.

Comment: Say you have an interface 'ice-cream provider'. A child wanting to buy and ice-cream would want to use an ice-cream provider. This would be shown be the child's arm grabbing the lollipop. Both an ice-cream van or a sweet shop would realise the 'ice-cream provider' interface; the child could use either realisation equally.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but what about the required interfaces, i'll assume that the child needs to get some money, so he must implement a money provider interface in order to do that.

Comment: Yes, if the ice-cream provider requires money and the child provides it, then there will be uses relationships in both directions. Though something else could provide it; you may add a constraint to the effect that the provider of the money has to be the receiver of the goods,  but someone else could equally pay for it.

Comment: This is a great example of where these diagrams can become the centre of a discussion on roles and responsibilities within an interaction. It also demonstrates how a diagram alone is often insufficient and/or not the best way to fully specify an interaction. (Nice example, @PeteKirkham. I love how the child's arm and the ice cream work as mnemonics for which is the service provider and which is the client.)

Answer (score 7):

**UML lollipop (ball and socket)**

It is a part of UML Component Diagrams

**Socket** - requires interface(consumer)

**Ball** - provides interface(producer)

[image]

Comment: In the picture, shouldn't the ball and socket notation be reversed? The client is the consumer (socket), and the dependency is the producer (ball), right?

Answer (score 2):

The Lolipop notation is used in the componenet digram.
As Far as i know, the lolipop can mean input and output
Where the **socket** (Half-Circle) reqiures input and the **ball** provides the input

[image]

**Reference**: OMG UML 2.5.1 specification, Retrived from: https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "lollipops" to represent an interface of a *component* - typically in a component diagram. They are not used to attach them to all/any classifiers.

Comment: In UML, a component is a classifier ( the metatype Component generalises Kernel::Class which generalises Kernal::Classifier )

Comment: True. So I should have said *all* classifiers - corrected that.